# open_basedir restriction in effect Unknown on line 0?

Tags: php, file, testing, host, open-basedir

I keep on getting these messages for every page at different times. What does line 0 mean?. Right now i'm using a free domain name from host(sub domain) and i'm using free hosting to test my site.
I put this sign->.. down below to replace the real names for private reasons. My host couldn't even fix the problem. I only access my files and folders in account. I guess that the type of hosting i have isn't good ?.Thanks

> Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/home/v1/sweet/123/htdocs/subscribe.php) is not within the
>   allowed path(s):
>   (/php_sessions:/tmp:/var/www/errors:/home/v1/bill/t/htdocs) in Unknown
>   on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required
>   '/home/v1/sweet/123/htdocs/subscribe.php' (include_path='.') in
>   Unknown on line 0

Comment: I think it's extremely confusing to use `..` to hide directory names as it's what the parent directory is called...

Comment: There are no lines to check at line 0 so it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Matti-Sorry I had to put it because it had my user id ..

Comment: Then use something else instead of `..`

Comment: ok.good idea. i'll change it

Answer (score 3):

`open_basedir restriction in effect [...] on line 0` means the `open_basedir` is too restrictive for PHP to open the script itself.

You can see that `/home/v1/sweet` is not within your `open_basedir` which is beneath `/home/v1/bill/`.

Comment: hi,it says this in the php configuration for open_basedir-> /php_sessions:/tmp:/var/www/errors:/home/ve/awd/uio/orange/htdocs

Comment: i don't see /home/v1/bill/ in configuration

Comment: Same rule applies: `/home/v1` is not within `/home/ve/`.

Comment: Thanks :). I will need to get a host that allows me to change php configuration.The host that i currently have wanted me to get expensive vps to stop getting messages instead of giving me answers. i wish that i can give you and Matti a +1 but i can't vote.

Comment: Actually on a typical shared hosting configuration the `open_basedir` is your webspace, even on the cheap ones. If your script is in `/home/v1/sweet/123/htdocs/subscribe.php` the root of the webspace is probably `/home/v1/sweet/123/htdocs/` and if they put `/home/ve/awd/uio/orange/htdocs` in `open_basedir` that is most certainly their mistake.

Comment: Thanks It is more clear to me. Yep I see that it is defiantly their mistake. I'll do site testing at another host.